# Delphi xe about Generics TList

Tags: delphi

sample:

```
type
  MyClass2=class;

  MyClass1=class
  private
    Fsub_test: TList<MyClass2>;
    procedure Setsub_test(const Value: TList<MyClass2>);
  public
    property sub_test:TList<MyClass2> read Fsub_test write Setsub_test;
  end;
  MyClass2=class
  private
    Fconent: string;
    procedure Setconent(const Value: string);
  public
    property conent:string read Fconent write Setconent;
  end;
```

now:

```
var
    ctx: TRttiContext;
    my1:MyClass1;
    p: TRttiType;
    pt: TRttiProperty;
begin
    ctx:=TRttiContext.create;
    my1:=MyClass1.Create;
    try
    p:=ctx.GetType(my1.ClassInfo);
    for pt in p.GetProperties do
    begin
      if copy(pt.PropertyType.Name.ToLower,1,6)='tlist<' then
      begin
        pt.SetValue(my1,pt.ClassType.Create); //error
        pt.SetValue(my1,TList<T>.create); 
//The T here, I'm going to pass in to the Myclass2 type, but I don't write Myclass2 directly, I get it 
      end;
    end;
    finally
      ctx.Free;
      my1.DisposeOf;
    end;
end;
```

1. I have know a class style
2. how to auto set my class to TList  in T?  TClass to T

example:

```
  var 
    t:TMyclass;

  TList<type(t)>.create;
```

I must auto transmit type to TList
  var(t) to TList not use

```
TList<TMyClass>.create
```

offcouse  type(t) not exsiste ,but how to do
thank!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That generic list should be declared for the final class (otherwise makes little sense to use generic list).

Comment: If you can't use TMyClass when you instantiate the list, why can you use TMyClass when you declare t? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My purpose here is to use RTTI. RTTI is very troublesome in generics. It can only achieve its purpose by curve

Comment: Because Rtti handles generics, I know the types inside the generics, but if that can be done, implement my ideas

Comment: That's not what you asked, no mention of RTTI. You will need to make it clear in the question. Although your comments don't make it any clearer. I asked what your real problem is. What is it?

Comment: Thank you. Look at me below

Comment: It's still unclear what your question is.

Comment: That's really no way, my description ability is limited, but this problem is not very understanding of RTTI, estimate also can not read

Comment: If you can't explain, we can't help